# unity AsyncOperation progress stays 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, asynchronous, loading

This is my code for the loading screen in unity 2017 and idk y its not working, the operation progress stays 0 :(

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject loadingScreen;
    public Slider slider;

    public void LoadLevel (string sceneIndex)
    {
        StartCoroutine (LoadAsynchronously(sceneIndex));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadAsynchronously (string sceneIndex)
    {
        AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync (sceneIndex);
        loadingScreen.SetActive (true);
        while (!operation.isDone) {
            float progress = Mathf.Clamp01 (operation.progress / 0.9f);
            Debug.Log (operation.progress);
            slider.value = progress;
            yield return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sry guys I had 2 scripts that control the scene load that's y it didn't work at first now i removed the other script and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

These lines work fine in my previous projects, you may try it.

```
IEnumerator LoadScene()
{
    yield return null;
    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneName);
    asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;
    while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
    {
        //Output the current progress
        Text_Progress.text = "Loading progress: " + (asyncOperation.progress * 100) + "%";
        // Check if the load has finished
        if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9f)
        {
            asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly it didnt work at all, atlease before everything work except the slider now even the loading screen doesnt show sicne i put it inseatd of the progress text.
as i said the only problem i had is the progress stays at 0 the value doesnt change